# Why don't we have rvalue of array type in C?

Tags: c

I read this statement in one discussion:

> There are no rvalues of array type in C. There are pointer lvalues and rvalues, integer lvalues and rvalues, structure lvalues and rvalues etc... But only lvalue arrays. When you try to convert an lvalue of array type to an rvalue, you no longer have an array, you have a pointer to the array's first member.

I am unable to get that when we cannot change the base address of array, so how can we use it as an lvalue, how can it's name be used on the Left hand side of the assignment statement?

Please explain briefly with example.

Comment: If you have `int array[10];` and then `int *ptr = array`, you can still use `ptr[1]` and it will be the same as `array[1]`. Or I miss your question?

Comment: Because the language was not designed to have them, and has never been modified to do so.  It would require a 'hidden loop' and C avoids those.  It would probably require a more complicated understanding of arrays, especially when passed as parameters to functions.

Comment: @tilz0R: In some languages, you can have (in C notation): `int a[10]; int b[10]; …initialization…; a = b;` and the contents of the entire array `b` are copied over the array `a`.  I believe the question is "Why can't you do that in C?"

Comment: C does not have those "rvalues" that you speak of...

Comment: Ok I understand now. No, C does not support that.

Comment: @KerrekSB you made me check, and indeed it seems that "rvalue" is not a standard C term. But isn't this a bit nitpicky?

Comment: @Quentin: I mean... you start a debate about the finer points of value categories and then complain when the going gets nitpicky? :-)

Comment: My question is how is array a non modifiable lvalue ? Why don't we have rvalue of array type in C when in general we can use array name only on RHS and not on LHS .

Comment: @KerrekSB Just passing by! But I read the question as "why is there no array temporaries". Calling them "non-lvalues", "rvalues", "temporaries" or something else does not affect the question IMHO :)

Comment: @Quentin: Think "why are there no array rvalues" is a good question, but unfortunately this didn't turn out to be that question. Instead it's something unrelated about "changing the base address".

Comment: "Why don't we have rvalue of array type in C?" --> it is not needed.  Other C mechanisms exist that fulfill the higher level coding goal.  OTOH, rvalue of array type, might be _convenient_ for a programmer.

Answer (score 2):

The C11 standard draft n1570 [footnote 64](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note64) says:

> The name **lvalue** comes originally from the assignment expression `E1 = E2`, in which the left operand `E1` is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an ***object locator value***. What is sometimes called **rvalue** is in this International Standard described as the **value of an expression**. An obvious example of an lvalue is an identifier of an object. As a further example, if `E` is a unary expression that is a pointer to an object, `*E` is an lvalue that designates the object to which `E` points.

So, a name of an array is an *object locator value*, as it is an object proper. However, in value context, the name of an array decays into a pointer to the first element.

If I remember correctly, even *rvalues* - that is, values of expressions of type `struct`s were a later (pre-ANSIsh) addition to the language. This could be done in a backwards-compatible manner, as structs wouldn't have decayed into pointers, but it couldn't have worked for arrays.

Comment: Since it decays into a pointer to first element , so it should be used as rvalue right , why it is used as lvalue when we can't change the base address of array .

Comment: Not exactly. `sizeof` takes an expression, but here an array does explicitly not decay.

Comment: @stackuser it is a(n) *lvalue* because it locates an object, not because it would be on the left side

Comment: @Olaf ¤%WA¤#"!¤ sizeof :D

Comment: Fine , but then why can't it be used as an rvalue when we can assign the name of the array to a pointer ?

Comment: @stackuser you're using it as an rvalue - it decayed into a pointer to the first element.

Comment: So it means that array can be used as an rvalue in C right ? But then why is this statement correct that we do not have rvalue of array type in C ?

Comment: For what it's worth, both `struct`s and `union`s are described in the first edition of K&R (1978).  I'm not sure when they were first introduced, but K&R1ed is years closer to the original invention of the language than it is to the publication of the first international C language standard.

Comment: @stackuser, no, an array cannot ever be used as an rvalue (* ).  You have to understand, however, that this is not meant as a rule that the programmer is obligated to obey, but rather is a consequence of language semantics.  Evaluation of an expression never produces an array, for anywhere that otherwise it would do, it produces a pointer instead.  ((*) except in the very special case of evaluating a variable-length array appearing as the operand of the `sizeof` operator.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger C rationale: "... Since the language **now** permits structure parameters, structure assignment and functions 
returning structures, the concept of a 
structure expression
 is now part of the C language", meaning that it wasn't at some point pre-C89

Comment: The C described in K&R First Edition didn't support structure assignment or passing or returning structures by value — though IIRC it was noted as likely to appear soon.  Enumerations were not a part of K&R 1st Edn C either, nor `void`, nor prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

Because C was initially written as a low level language. AFAIK it was the first language to have no input/output instruction, the rationale behind being that IO should be coded in a C library.

As a low level language, it was heavily making use of *addresses* (read pointer). In assembly language, an array is just a consecutive zone of memory for which you know first address. In old K&R C, an array was nothing more than that, and functions were only allowed to return scalars or pointers, because these are the types that can fit in a register.

Those were the good old days where you found everywhere tons of dangling pointer examples because as soon as you were trying to return more that a single value you lost.

Then C (ANSI C) begin to behave as a more civil language. Functions got prototypes to limit the risk of passing a wrong type, and some aggregates (structures) were allowed as both parameters and return types of functions. But as arrays were extensively used through pointers and as many existing codes actually depended on the rule *an array decays to a pointer to its first element*, no one wanted to break that to allow to process arrays the same as struct objects.

Said differently, as structures and arrays are collectively designed as aggregates in some part of the standard, we could easily imagine a way to accept the same syntactic rules for both. And some other languages do. But it could break so much legacy code that it will probably never happen.

TL/DR: it is the way C behaves since its beginning, and a lot of code depends on this behaviour. If you do not like that, you should learn Java which is a much more recent language with less quirks. But less possibilities too because the lack of pointer notion...

Comment: FWIW, structures were introduced long before ANSI C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: If I correctly remember, functions could not return structures in K&R C - but it is looong time now...

Comment: You are correct.  The first edition of K&R says "[...] the only operations that you can perform on a structure are to take its address with & or to access one of its members.  This implies that they may not be assigned to or copied as a unit, and that they can not be passed to or returned from functions."  The text goes on to remark that you can freely use pointers to structures with functions.  Of course, ANSI removed those restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an array has lvalue but the thing is it is not modifiable lvalue. Other thing to be noted here is **array name is always an lvalue.** Because when you use array as rvalue its the pointer pointing the first element of the array. And pointer always have rvalue. When you refer an array you mean all the elements of the array and not just first element.

So as a conclusion I'd say that **array name is always an lvalue that too not modifiable**

Comment: Pointers are not "always rvalues" -- what about `int *a;`?

Comment: In what sense is it non modifiable lvalue ,please clarify .

Comment: int arr [20];
int p[10];
arr =p;// not possible
arr = 5; //not possible

Comment: Fine , but then how is it used as an rvalue ,  but then why can't it be used as an rvalue when we can assign the name of the array to a pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to get that when we cannot change the base address of array, so how can we use it as an lvalue, how can it's name be used on the Left hand side of the assignment statement?

You have a core misconception here.  As @AnttiHaapala already covered, some expression *expr* being an lvalue does not necessarily mean that it is an acceptable left-hand operand of the assignment operator.  C has some simpler examples of such expressions: any whose type is `const`-qualified.

There are a couple of ways to conceptualize why arrays cannot appear on the left-hand side of an assignment statement.  Consider these declarations:

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };
```

In light of those declarations and C's rules for evaluating expressions, how should we then interpret the (invalid) statement

```
a = b;
```

?  In order to evaluate the assignment operation, we must first evaluate the operands.  The sub-expression `b`, consisting of the name of an array-valued variable, evaluates to a pointer to the first element of that array (equivalent to `&b[0]`).  A pointer is not an array, so the result does not have the correct type for assignment to variable `a`.

That would be enough by itself, but we're not done.  To evaluate the assignment expression, we must *also* evaluate the sub-expression `a`.  As the name of an array-valued variable, this sub-expression *also* evaluates to a pointer to the first element of the array.  Moreover, *that pointer is not an lvalue*, so it is not an acceptable left operand of the `=` operator.

And as if that weren't enough, the standard also says

> A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that **does not have array type**,
>   does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified
>   type, [...]

([Paragraph 6.3.2.1/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1); emphasis added).  Thus, even if you ignored the decay of array to pointer on the left-hand side of an assignment operator, the assignment is still invalid because arrays are not *modifiable* lvalues under any circumstance.

Choose whichever of these explanations makes the most sense to you, or indeed choose all of them.  The standard provides multiple ways to come to the same conclusion; although it's not perfect, it is pretty good at being self-consistent.

Comment: Thanks , I got some of your points , still I am confused in following points :  1. When the sub-expression a is evaluated , it decayed to a pointer to first element of the array , and that pointer is not an lvalue , when the pointer refers to a memory location of the first element , why is it not an lvalue , rather we should say that it is non modifiable lvalue ,Please correct me If I am wrong .                                                                          2. I can do int *ptr=a ; which means I can use array name as rvalue , so why can't we have rvalue of array type ?

Comment: @stackuser, (1) what reason do you have to think that the pointer value produced by decay of an array to a pointer should be an *l*value?  The pointer value you get from explicitly doing `&a[0]` isn't one.  The result is just a value; there is no associated persistent *storage*, which is the fundamental characteristic of an lvalue.  (2) C does not define the term "rvalue".  Nevertheless, it is important to understand that in your expression, it is the result of the array's decay to a pointer that is being assigned, not the array itself.  This is a question of *semantics*, not *syntax*.